# How can I use "ng serve" with multiple apps hosted through an nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: angular, nginx, webpack-dev-server

My employer has a number of Angular 2+ apps that are under active development.  These apps are hosted behind an nginx reverse proxy. For example, during development, one app might be reachable at:

```
https://localhost/my-app-1
```

while another might be found at:

```
https://localhost/my-app-2
```

To accomplish this proxying behavior, I configure each Angular app to use a different port when hosted using `ng serve`:

```
// in angular.json
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "projects": {
        "my-project": {
            "architect": {
                "serve": {
                    "options": {

                        // each app gets its own port
                        "port": 4201

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I use nginx to proxy traffic to the appropriate port using this nginx configuration:

```
# proxy my-app-1 requests
location ^~ /my-app-1/ {

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4201/;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

# proxy my-app-2 requests
location ^~ /my-app-1/ {

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4202/;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

# proxy ng serve live reload traffic
location ^~ /sockjs-node/ {

    # Notice that the port is hardcoded
    # in this proxy configuration
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4201;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

This works, with one caveat - the `/sockjs-node/` traffic is only routed to **one** of the two apps (in this example, the one hosted at port 4201).  Because of this, the live reload feature only works with one app at a time.

Here's my question: is there a way to configure nginx or the Angular development server to allow me to use live reload for **all** of my apps when using `ng serve` through an nginx proxy? For example, I'd like to have two instances of `ng serve` running simultaneously - one for `https://localhost/my-app-1` and one for `https://localhost/my-app-2` - and have live reload work for both apps.

I've tried conditionally routing the traffic based on the HTTP Referer header (the `$http_referer` variable in nginx), but not all of the live reload traffic includes this header.

I'm using version 6 of Angular and the Angular CLI.

Comment: You should not use `ng serve` in production, just as the angular-cli console output warns you. It is intended only for development, as it is unstable and the code not optimized. Instead you should build the app for production with `ng build`, after which you will get the fully compiled output in the destination-folder (by default `/dist/`).

Comment: @Phil - Yes, we only use this setup for development.  For production we have a different build process and hosting setup.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm in the same position, though I'm using a different proxy.

Comment: @PlaidPhantom - Nope, I just ended up doing a lot of manual `nginx.conf` editing :(

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to run `ng serve --publicHost https://localhost/my-app-1` for your first app. And the corresponsing public hosts for the other apps. This will ensure that the traffic from `/sockjs-node/` is send to different urls.

From the angular docs of [--publicHost](https://angular.io/cli/serve) "The URL that the browser client (or live-reload client, if enabled) should use to connect to the development server. Use for a complex dev server setup, such as one with reverse proxies."

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to setup similar case with [express](https://expressjs.com/) and [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware).

The most relevant express code is following:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const url = require('url');

const app = express(); 
// ... some express setup

app.use('/my-app-1', proxy({
  target: 'http://127.0.0.1:4202',
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: { '^/my-app-1': '' },
  xfwd: true,
  ws: true
}));

// analogically the same for 'my-app-2'

// redirect to default app
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.redirect(
  url.format({ pathname: '/my-app-1', query: req.query }))
);

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(5000);
```

I also changed `<base href=...>` in both apps in `index.html`:

```
<base href="/my-app-1/">
```

Make sure you use assets without leading slash, like: `<img src="assets/my-image.png">`

In my case I needed some more angular config to handle assets with [ngx-translate](http://www.ngx-translate.com/):

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient, APP_BASE_HREF]
      }
    })
  ],
  declarations: // ...
  exports: // ...
  providers: [
    // ...
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my-app-1/' }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

export function httpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient, baseHref) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, baseHref + 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

And finally, I had to setup `publicHost` as suggested by @Dennis - I have updated config for both apps in `angular.json`, in `architect.serve.options` part:

```
"publicHost": "http://localhost:5000/my-app-1"
```

And works as expected, including hot reload.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This is now fixed with [Angular CLI v8.3.14](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v8.3.14)

For older versions this issue can be fixed by using `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`:

- `npm install @angular-builders/custom-webpack --save-dev` or `yarn add @angular-builders/custom-webpack --dev`
- update `angular.json` as described [here](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack#example)
- add a `./extra-webpack.config.js` file with

```
module.exports = (config, options) => {
  if(!config.devServer) {
    // do nothing for `ng build`
    return config;
  }
  return {
    ...config,
    devServer: {
      ...config.devServer,
      sockPath: `${config.devServer.publicPath}/sockjs-node`
    }
  };
};
```

I've setup a demo project that applies the fix:
https://github.com/micmro/angular-base-href-reload-socket-path-workaround

Comment: absolutely not working solution, no changes

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a similar setup working by using subdomains of localhost.

- https://app1.localhost:5080
- https://app2.localhost:5080

...and so on

Looks like chrome based browsers will resolve any subdomain of localhost to the localhost address. (I've only tested with Chrome and Edge on Windows)

Alternatively you could always add host entries on your machine.

Nginx config looks like this:

```
server{ 
    listen 5080;
    server_name app1.localhost

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200
    }
}
```

....repeat the entire server block for each app, just change the server name and proxy_pass settings

I'm listening on port 5080 but you can of course use any port.